# My ____ is still aching from standing too close

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

**Please try your best to solve the problem below. GOOD LUCK!!**

*2042024440*

*420202020*

*2020202*

[image]

???

Hint:

> Count!!

Bigger hint:

> Think of the first part of the puzzle as 3 rows of something and the 4s all highlighting something.

Comment: If, as the title suggests, the answer is a single word, then the [[tag:word]] tag applies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The numbers at the top

> match the layout of a standard qwerty keyboard, the 4s match the vowels to confirm this

The grid

> has 26 cells, putting the alphabet in and reading the highlighted cells in rainbow order results in `PKJJFFYCB`, nothing useful.

> instead filling the grid out in qwerty order, you get
>  `HAPPYYNEW`, very close.

> rearranging the sentence yields "Happy new y", which is missing "ear", taking the title into consideration that must be the answer! Maybe try enjoying your fireworks from a distance in 2025 :-)

Comment: Haha well done!! Welcome to PSE!!